# How to check Logistic model assumptions in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, assumptions

I am using `glmrob` with `family = "binomial"` in a regression model with a dichotomous dependent variable. How do I test whether the logistic model assumptions are met? What are the assumptions I should be testing for and what methods/packages do you suggest I can make use of in R to do the same?